# How do I delete a second 12.04 OS from my computer?

Tags: 12.04

The whole world will know now that I am not the brightest bulb - OS wise anyway.  I was having problems with Ubuntu 12.04 so thought I would re-install it.  After it began, I realized I really did not want this and couldn't stop it.  It installed a 2nd OS with the same name in another partition.  How do I delete that new OS?

Comment: Install `Parted` using `sudo apt-get install parted` and then include the output of `sudo parted print all`. It will help us see which partitions you have. You can fix this from inside the Ubuntu installation that you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Backup all your data in Ubuntu, Windows, etc.**
2. Determine the partition in which the second Ubuntu is installed.
3. Boot from Live CD/USB and choose the **Try Ubuntu** option.
4. Open **Gparted** and delete the partition(s) with the extra Ubuntu.
5. Using **Gparted** expand the existing partition(s) to reclaim the unused space.
6. Boot to Ubuntu from the hard drive and open a terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter: `sudo
   update-grub` to remove the deleted entry from the boot menu.

If GRUB the boot-loader gets messed up and the computer does not boot to Ubuntu, follow the second option described at [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix reinstall GRUB. [Also see this detailed instruction for installing GRUB from the Live CD/USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/).

Hope this helps

Comment: doesnt he have to run a grub-install at some point ?
probably, the grub most recently installed is reading its configuration from the partition the wants to delete ...

Comment: Thanks @josinalvo, I have added a link to boot-repair for the situation you mention.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question.  Wish any of you could come to my house and do it for me, my eyes have glazed over!  Will try the easiest one first and will let you know!  Again, thanks!

Comment: @Karina, You are welcome. You can take a snap-shot of the gparted window by clicking Al+PrintScreen while the Gparted window is active. Add the image to your question if you are not sure which partition to delete. When satisfied, consider accepting one of the answers to be correct. This will help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Did your new install also overwrite GRUB? In that case, restore GRUB from the desired installation by following:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

After that, use a disk-management tool like 'Disks' to format the left-over partitions and put them to better use.

p.s. if that was the stupidest thing mankind has ever done, we'd be living in a better world now :)